# Inserting PHP code inside input value

Tags: php, html

I have this code:

```
<form METHOD="POST" action=" ">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="op1" value="<?= $op1?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>+</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="op2" value="<?= $op1?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="="></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text"  name="rezultat" value="<?= $op1+$op2 ?>" disabled ></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and the browser show me in the input value something like this:`<?= $op1?>`
I want to do a simple calculator, but something is wrong and I don't know what. Can anyone help me?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Please check short php tag is enabled on your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be the correct syntax:

```
<form method="POST" action=" ">
  <table>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="op1" value="<?php echo $op1; ?>"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>+</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="op2" value="<?php echo $op1; ?>"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="="></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"  name="rezultat" value="<?php echo ($op1+$op2); ?>" disabled ></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

The short codes you use have to be configured before usage. Seems that is not the case. Do first try with the long codes as mentioned here. Also you need an "action" for the form, unless you handle it using ajax.

You might also want to take a look at using css for layout purposes. That way you can simplify your html markup a lot, because you won't need a table structure for positioning the tags. That would be more elegant, more flexible and much better for handicapped users.

Comment: Thank you. I learn from a book how to do a simple calculator in php and there they use table structure. Now, I use "echo"  instead "=" , but I don't understant what I must to write in "action". I search on google and I found something like <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>. This book don't explain me how to use internal php code to develop this calculator.

Comment: // I discover my problem
$submit=$_POST['submit'];
$op1 = $_POST['op1'];
$op2 = $_POST['op2'];
$rezultat = $op1+$op2;
if ($submit) {
 echo $rezultat;
}
?>
<hr>
<form method="POST" action="script.php">
  <table>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="op1" value="<?php echo $op1; ?>"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>+</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="op2" value="<?php echo $op1; ?>"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="="></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"  name="rezultat" value="<?php echo ($op1+$op2); ?>" disabled ></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>

Answer (score 1):

You should make space bettwen php tags and your code

```
  value="<?php echo $op1; ?>"
```

instead:

```
  value="<?= $op1?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the php [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/) and documentation to practice the correct syntax.

```
<form METHOD="POST" action=" ">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="op1" value="<?php echo $op1; ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>+</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="op2" value="<?php echo $op1; ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="="></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text"  name="rezultat" value="<?php echo $op1+$op2; ?>" disabled ></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Use echo method to print values on view.

Add a semicolon at the end of the statement.